# How do I check if a value type has a value of IntPtr.Zero

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms

So I am writing a `Xamarin` application and I have built a `CustomRenderer`

now my method:

```
horizontalScrollView.ScrollTo(this.Width, 0);
```

keeps throwing an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
>   10-21 12:10:41.898 E/AndroidRuntime(15053): Parameter name: jobject
>   10-21 12:10:41.898 E/AndroidRuntime(15053): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallIntMethod (intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:378
>   10-21 12:10:41.898 E/AndroidRuntime(15053): at Android.Views.View.get_Width ()

So looking at the exception and from my breakpoints I find that the problem is that when I hover over `this.Width` I get `'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero` instead of an `integer` so I try to defensively code against this and do:

```
if (this.Width != IntPtr.Zero)
{
   horizontalScrollView.ScrollTo(this.Width, 0);
}
```

but this doesnt compile and gives me the error:

> Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and
>   'IntPtr'

So my questions is. Is there a way to check whether a `value type` is equal to `IntPtr.Zero`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working on a custom renderer I assume you are using Xamarin.Forms.
You can't check for `IntPtr.Zero` here. The `IntPtr` is set internally by Xamarin.Forms. You have usually no access to the wrong pointer. So you can't see it's there but you receive an error when you access the `Width` property because it works internally with that pointer.

There are two possible causes for this error:

1. You didn't initialize the control properly. So it contains null pointers.
2. There is a bug in Xamarin.Forms. Test your code against other versions of Xamarin.Forms. If the error doesn't occur in a different version or you believe it's a bug then file it [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check against the jobject and not against the property-value 'width'.